# Boostrap 4 Row not occupying entire length of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, row

I am working on a bootstrap 4, 4 column layout. I'm starting with just 3 columns. I have an outer div container, and an inner row with 3 columns. When I add borders to all the containers I can see that the row does not flex to fill the entire parent container div. I've tried a number of CSS properties and I just can't seem to figure out why it won't stretch to fit the parent container. Ideally I'd love to see the center column width be 100% minus the sum percentage of the other two columns (which have arrow images in them). Check out the jsfiddle to see the code and the resulting render.

(mostly) Complete code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ukd5stc0/

Code sample as required by stackoverflow:

```
<div class="container touchpointContainer">
  <div class="row tall wide">
    <div class="col-1 centerVertically">
      <a onclick="advanceReview(-1)">
        <img class="prev" src="leftArrow.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 centerVertically mainText">
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore"
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 centerVertically">
      <a onclick="advanceReview(1)">
        <img class="next" src="rightArrow.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wide` class is making the row have a `width:100%`, and rows typically are wider than 100% because of the left and right margin's being set to `-15px`. Remove the wide class and you'll be good.